# PLS-00306 dbms_scheduler.create_job

Tags: oracle, jobs, plsql-developer

I'm not an expert about DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB and i've been asked to create a job. When i run it i get these errors:

```
ORA-06550: line2,column 2
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CREATE_JOB'
```

My statement is:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name           =>  'ME.Delete_org',
   job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
   job_action         =>  'BEGIN delete_org_sre_package.process_org_sre_deletions; END;',
   start_date         =>  '23-NOV-17 11.00.00 PM',
   repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=WEEKLY; BYDAY=FRI; BYHOUR=23; BYMINUTE=0; BYSECOND=0;',
   auto_drop          =>   FALSE,
   end_date           =>   NULL,
   enabled            =>   TRUE,
   comments           =>  'Every Friday at 11pm');
END;
/
```

Any ideas of what i'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that was causing this issue was the `start_date` bit, i guess because of conflict with `repeat_interval`. Anyway, I ran it without `start_date` and it worked.

Comment: Conflict with repeat interval? More likely because START_DATE is supposed to accept a timestamp and you gave it a string.  How does oracle know what part of the string is the year? Month? etc.  It depends on the NLS_* setting which may not be what you think.  set START_DATE => SYSTIMESTAMP.  Be aware that START_DATE is not when the job actually starts, but when the schedule goes into effect.

Comment: Thanks @EdStevens, i'll keep it in my mind for the next time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to review each of the parameters in the docs, located at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72300.  Specfically, take a look at 'job_action' for your specified 'job_type' of "STORED_PROCEDURE".

"The action is the *name* of the stored procedure. "  (emphasis mine).  You are saying the action is a *command* -- "execute".

Also, does your procedure "delete_org_sre_package.process_org_sre_deletions" have any input or output parameters?

Comment: Hi @EdStevens, thanks, i'll keep your link in my useful links ;) 
In the end i found out the problem for my issue on Friday. Below my solution (very simple)